# Why does my line graph shift leftward when I plot it with a boxplot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to combine a boxplot with a line graph of the same dataframe. However, when I plot my linegraph of df.max(), it shifts my line leftward by 1 unit. How do I solve this problem?

```
    Date    1 mo    2 mo    3 mo    6 mo    1 yr    2 yr    3 yr    5 yr    7 yr    10 yr   20 yr   30 yr
Date                                                    
2019-08-19  2019-08-19  2.06    1.96    1.94    1.90    1.75    1.53    1.49    1.47    1.54    1.60    1.88    2.08
2019-08-20  2019-08-20  2.05    1.96    1.94    1.89    1.72    1.50    1.44    1.42    1.49    1.55    1.84    2.04
2019-08-21  2019-08-21  2.03    1.98    1.97    1.90    1.77    1.56    1.50    1.47    1.54    1.59    1.87    2.07
2019-08-22  2019-08-22  2.10    2.02    2.00    1.91    1.79    1.61    1.53    1.50    1.56    1.62    1.90    2.11
2019-08-23  2019-08-23  2.07    2.02    1.97    1.87    1.73    1.51    1.43    1.40    1.46    1.52    1.82    2.02
2019-08-26  2019-08-26  2.09    2.03    2.01    1.90    1.75    1.54    1.47    1.43    1.49    1.54    1.84    2.04
2019-08-27  2019-08-27  2.07    2.03    1.98    1.94    1.77    1.53    1.43    1.40    1.44    1.49    1.77    1.97
2019-08-28  2019-08-28  2.07    2.04    1.99    1.89    1.74    1.50    1.42    1.37    1.42    1.47    1.76    1.94
2019-08-29  2019-08-29  2.10    2.03    1.99    1.89    1.75    1.53    1.44    1.40    1.46    1.50    1.78    1.97
2019-08-30  2019-08-30  2.10    2.04    1.99    1.89    1.76    1.50    1.42    1.39    1.45    1.50    1.78    1.96
```

I've tried plotting them individually as a boxplot and a line itself but there seems to be no issue. The issue arises when I combine them.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize = (12, 8))
plt.plot(df.median())
plt.plot(df.max())
df.boxplot()
plt.show()
```

My output:

[image: Output]

As seen from the image, the orange and blue line shifts leftward, how do I fix this issue?

Comment: Actually, the lines stay where they are, but the boxplot creates its labels at axis positions starting at `1` instead of `0`. It also relabels the axes.

Comment: I do not have enough rep to answer my own qn. So here's my answer after taking reference  `plt.plot(list(range(1, 13)), df.max())`.
In a way, I am hardcoding it, is there a better solution?